# Linkedin Api: can't find replies endpoint

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been trying to retrieve a company's replies to comments on their posts, but I can't seem to find an endpoint for that. Linkedin API has endpoints for getting a company's updates but they give me back only the update's comments, not the replies. Likewise, I can't reply a comment over their API either.

Also, something strange I've noticed is that if I access my company's page: https://www.linkedin.com/company/10951150 I can see all the posts and comments but replies are hidden. However if I request a specific update: https://www.linkedin.com/hp/update/6209448910621077505 I can see both comments and replies. So it might actually be a bug.

Comment: did you have any joy finding this?